# Edge problems with matplotlib and cartopy

Tags: python, matplotlib, cartopy

I was trying to put sentinel images together using matplotlib and cartopy. It mostly worked, instead the edges are blurry on the edge like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aCnvl.png)

```
print('globe')
north_crs = ccrs.NorthPolarStereo()
north_globe = ccrs.Globe(semiminor_axis=90)
north_xform_crs = ccrs.Geodetic(globe=north_globe)
colorlists = [None] * len(file_paths)
lonslist = [None] * len(file_paths)
latslist = [None] * len(file_paths)

fig = plt.figure()
GeoAxes._pcolormesh_patched = Axes.pcolormesh
ax = plt.axes(projection=north_crs)
ax.coastlines()
data = np.zeros([image_pixel, image_pixel], dtype=np.uint8)
GeoAxes._pcolormesh_patched = Axes.pcolormesh

for i in range(len(file_paths)):
    print(f'file #{i}')
    color_list, lons, lats = getInfos(file_paths[i], north_crs, north_xform_crs)
    colorlists[i] = color_list
    lonslist[i] = lons
    latslist[i] = lats
    ax.pcolormesh(lons, lats, data, transform=north_crs, color=color_list)
```

I did try putting the matrices into one. It worked. But each sentinel image is 10980*10980 and I don't think my computer or the server I have access to can handle this amount of data to give me an image of north pole

Comment: Why are you patching pcolormesh? Cartopy has its own version of that function for a reason, so your overriding of that is suspect and could be related to your problem.

Comment: @DopplerShift It just does not run without that line. I didn't encounter such problem when working with MODIS, but it still has the same problem